# I wrote an if/elseif-statement but it only gives me the first condition answer, why?

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement

Also I had an error (Unreachable code)

The purpose of the program is to give the plural of an English word

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  char word[100];
  int len;

  printf("plz enter a word : ");
  fflush(stdin);
  gets(word);
  len=strlen(word);
  char nword[100]={(char)malloc(len+3)};

  if(word[len-1]=='s'||'S')
  {
      strcpy(nword,word);
      nword[len]='e';
      nword[len+1]='s';
      nword[len+2]='\0';
      printf("the plural of your word is (%s)\n",nword);
      free(nword);
  }
  if(word[len-1]=='s'||'S')
  {
      strcpy(nword,word);
      nword[len]='e';
      nword[len+1]='s';
      nword[len+2]='\0';
      printf("the plural of your word is (%s)\n",nword);
      free(nword);
  }
  else if(word[len-1]=='x'||'X')
  {
      strcpy(nword,word);
      nword[len]='e';
      nword[len+1]='s';
      nword[len+2]='\0';
      printf("the plural of your word is (%s)\n",nword);
      free(nword);
  }
  else if(word[len-1]=='z'||'Z')
  {
      strcpy(nword,word);
      nword[len]='e';
      nword[len+1]='s';
      nword[len+2]='\0';
      printf("the plural of your word is (%s)\n",nword);
      free(nword);
  }
  else if(word[len-2]=='c'||'C'&&word[len-1]=='h'||'H')
  {
      strcpy(nword,word);
      nword[len]='e';
      nword[len+1]='s';
      nword[len+2]='\0';
      printf("the plural of your word is (%s)\n",nword);
      free(nword);
  }
  else if(word[len-2]=='s'||'S'&&word[len-1]=='h'||'H')
  {
      strcpy(nword,word);
      nword[len]='e';
      nword[len+1]='s';
      nword[len+2]='\0';
      printf("the plural of your word is (%s)\n",nword);
      free(nword);
  }
  else printf("ddd");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fflush` and input stream is undefined behaviour. For the warning (this is no error): Think about it. See which line it is and check your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'S'` always evaluates to true, which in turn means `if(word[len-1]=='s'||'S')` will always evaluate to true, which in turn means the following `else` branch is never reached.

You probably meant

```
if(word[len-1]=='s'|| word[len-1]=='S')
```